# Error 504 Gateway Time-out ajax jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, timeout

jQuery.ajax that returns me the following error

> 504 - error - Gateway Time-out

```js
request = $.ajax({
    url: Raiz + "/informes/Inventario/pdfInventarioAlmacenValorado.php", 
    type: "POST", 
    data: data, 
    timeout: (600 * 1000), 
    success: function(resp) {
        SalidaReporte = resp;
    }, 
    error: function(jX, err, errT) {
        alert(jX.status + "\n" + err + "\n" + errT);
    }
});
```

A may be due the problem ?? PHP is not the problem. There may be some limitation on the web server that causes this error? On my local server it does not fail. Thanks!

Comment: Any 500 error means that the issue is server side. The specific error in this case means the server took too long to respond to the request. You should investigate the `pdfInventarioAlmacenValorado.php` to see what could cause the problem. If you don't have access to the server, give the provider a report on the issue.

Comment: pdfInventarioAlmacenValorado.php file is not the problem

it is true that it takes a long time to respond so I'm trying to set the ajax timeout to (600 * 1000)

However not seem to work

Comment: The jQuery timeout is not the problem - the server is timing out. You shouldn't really have anything that slow running under a request anyway. Use a scheduler to execute long-running tasks in the background and alert the user when it completes.

Answer (score 0):

I Found one working solution posted by [#david-hoerster](https://stackoverflow.com/users/237808/david-hoerster)

If your error event handler takes the three arguments (XMLHttpRequest, textstatus, and message) when a timeout happens, the status arg will be 'timeout'

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/ajax_json_echo/",
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "json",
    timeout: 1000,
    success: function(response) { alert(response); },
    error: function(xmlhttprequest, textstatus, message) {
        if(textstatus==="timeout") {
            alert("got timeout");
        } else {
            alert(textstatus);
        }
    }
});​
```

With [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u3f9C/), you can test ajax calls -- it will wait 2 seconds before responding. I put the timeout set at 1 second, so it should error out and pass back a textstatus of 'timeout' to the error handler.